# Tipos ShortString, AnsiChar y AnsiString en Delphi Tokio para Linux

Tags: linux, delphi, tipos

En Delphi Tokio para Linux, cuáles son los tipos equivalentes de:

- ShortString
- AnsiChar
- AnsiString

Envío este bloque de código para mostrar como funcionan estos tipos para Windows pero para Linux no:

```
     program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

Var
  Ch1   : Char;
  SStr1 : String;
  AStr1 : String;
{$IFNDEF LINUX}
  Ch2   : AnsiChar;
  SStr2 : ShortString;
  AStr2 : AnsiString;
{$ENDIF}
  Ch3   : UTF8Char;
  SStr3 : String;
  AStr3 : UTF8String;
begin
  try
    { TODO -oUser -cConsole Main : Insert code here }
    Ch1:= 'A'; SStr1:='AaBbCcD'; AStr1:='1234567';
    WriteLn('"',Ch1,'"-"',SStr1,'"-"',AStr1,'"');
{$IFNDEF LINUX}
    Ch2:= 'A'; SStr2:='AaBbCcD'; AStr2:='1234567';
    WriteLn('"',Ch2,'"-"',SStr2,'"-"',AStr2,'"');
{$ELSE}
    WriteLn('En Delphi Linux no se cuenta con los tipos Ansichar, ShortString y AnsiString');
    WriteLn('Cuáles son los tipos equivalentes?');
{$ENDIF}
    Ch3:= 'A'; SStr3:='AaBbCcD'; AStr3:='1234567';
    WriteLn('"',Ch3,'"-"',SStr3,'"-"',AStr3,'"');
    ReadLn;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No hay tipos realmente *equivalentes* a `ShortString`, `AnsiChar` o `AnsiString`, entre otros, en el compilador conocido como *NextGen*, que es el compilador que se utiliza para plataformas móviles y [Linux](https://www.embarcadero.com/es/products/rad-studio/whats-new-in-10-2-tokyo).

De acuerdo al documento *[Migrating Delphi Code to Mobile from Desktop](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Migrating_Delphi_Code_to_Mobile_from_Desktop)*, los posibles sustitutos podrían ser:

- `System.AnsiString`, `System.ShortString`: Eliminar completamente su uso, considerar `array of byte` (yo añado `TBytes`)
- `System.AnsiChar`: `System.Char`, `System.Byte`, `System.UInt8`

Al hablar de sustitutos aquí, hablamos de tipos de datos que podrían albergar la misma información, pero que van a tener alguna variación en la manera de procesarla, o de almacenarla.